# How to print out if elements inside an list is a number or a word?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to write a program to print out if the element in a list is a word or a number. After some trial and error, I cooked up this:

```
a = [1, 'Ladder', 2, 'Bat', 3, 'Cat', 4, 'Zoo'] 
isnumber = "{} is a number"
isword = "{} is a word" 

for x in range(len(a)):
    t = isinstance(a[x],int)
    if t:
        print(isnumber.format(a[x]))
    t = isinstance(a[x],str)
    if t:
        print(isword.format(a[x]))
```

Is there a simple way to do the same?

Comment: Should "1" be considered a number or a word?

Comment: And 3.5, 2e12 are also numbers?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use range, instead directly iterate over the list

```py
a = [1, 'Ladder', 2, 'Bat', 3, 'Cat', 4, 'Zoo'] 
isnumber = "{} is a number"
isword = "{} is a word" 

for x in a:
    if isinstance(x,int):
        print(isnumber.format(x))
    
    if isinstance(x,str):
        print(isword.format(x))
```

You can use f-strings for better visibility

```py
a = [1, 'Ladder', 2, 'Bat', 3, 'Cat', 4, 'Zoo']

for x in a:
    if isinstance(x,int):
        print(f"{x} is a number")
    
    if isinstance(x,str):
        print(f"{x} is a word")
```

If you want in one line, Use list comprehension  :D

```py
a = [1, 'Ladder', 2, 'Bat', 3, 'Cat', 4, 'Zoo']

[print(f"{x} is a number") if isinstance(x,int) else print(f"{x} is a word") if isinstance(x,str) else "" for x in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the same code, just removed redundant actions

```py
a = [1, 'Ladder', 2, 'Bat', 3, 'Cat', 4, 'Zoo'] 
isnumber = "{} is a number"
isword = "{} is a word" 

for x in range(len(a)):
    if(isinstance(a[x],int)):
        print(isnumber.format(a[x]))
    if(isinstance(a[x],str)):
        print(isword.format(a[x]))
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to index and then dereference the list - just iterate. And use f-strings for formatting.

```
a = [1, 'Ladder', 2, 'Bat', 3, 'Cat', 4, 'Zoo'] 

for value in a:
    if isinstance(value, int):
        print(f"{value} is a number")
    elif isinstance(value, str):
        print(f"{value} is a word")
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    a = [1, 'Ladder', 2, 'Bat', 3, 'Cat', 4, 'Zoo']
    for i in a:
        if str(i).isdigit():
            print(f'{i} is a number')
        else:
            print(f'{i} is a word'))
```